# Prevent element from being manipulated with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently building a small ad network, mainly intended to be used at our own websites.

The ads are loaded by including a script on the site, like...

```
<script src="http://someurl.com/somejs.js"></script>
```

Anywhere I place the script line, it's gets replaced with the ad content, inside a  with inline styling.
Must ads will be HTML, and that's what troubles me...

For example, lets pretend that the ad content is something like

```
<div style="height: 150px; width: 90px; overflow: hidden; display: inline-block;"><p>Buy cheap buttons</p><p><img src="deliciousButtons.png" /></p></div>
```

And then lets pretend that the content is loaded into a webpage, where someone has the following in his stylesheet:

```
img { border: 1px solid red; }
```

Now the image in the ad gets a red border - bummer.

My only solution would be to use iframes... However, I've never really liked iframes.

Is there a html-element, where you can place HTML inside and everything placed inside is not susceptible to any stylesheet preferences - only inline styling?

... If no. Any suggestions on how to do it? With no iframes :)

Comment: It sounds like you want [shadow DOM](http://glazkov.com/2011/01/14/what-the-heck-is-shadow-dom/). (See in particular the section entitled *Reaching into Shadows with CSS*: "`One other trick up the sleeve is the ability to control how and whether CSS reaches into the shadow subtree.`") **Sadly**, since shadow DOM isn't standardized or implemented yet, you're stuck with iframes.

Comment: You describe what you want, and it is precisely an iframe. Then you say you don't want to use iframes. So you want a thing that's an iframe but not an iframe. What is the point of this exercise?

Comment: apsillers: Damn right, that is what I want... However, for now I will let every ad be generated with it's own wrapper with a unqiue ID (e.g. id="someName-adID-*datetime*") and then have my script append a style tag to the <head>, which will then hold a CSS reset to all elements that are child of the specific unique wrapper. From that point on, then inline styling controls the elements.

Comment: @EibergDK: Don't forget to mark all of your rules as !important or any of those that people write will still override your styles.

Answer (score 2):

You can override the inherited styles, but for it to work properly, you will need to everride every possible CSS option and probably mark such overrides as !important, really, iframes is the best way to accomplish that, another possibility is to use static images or flash, but i guess this is also out of the possible options.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following.
Add a class which you don't want the style.

`<img src="deliciousButtons.png" class="no-border"/>`

Then on your css.

```
img:not(.no-border) {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aqN8a/)

Comment: In this case, I can not rely of having access to the stylesheet and therefore skipping specific classes is not an option - also it can be manipulated to easy. Shadow DOM's was what I was looking for, however it looks like I'll have to use a work around for now (this is not it though).